# Oci in php much faster than occi?

Tags: c++, oracle

why below code is faster in php (oci) than c++ (occi)? 
For 50k rows php execute script in 30s. Program is executing in 5 min!

```
/* php - oci code */
$s = oci_parse($c, 'select "client" from test');
oci_execute($s, OCI_DEFAULT);  

while ($row = oci_fetch_array($s, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) 
{
    $i++;
    if ($i%1000 == 0) echo $i.' '.$row['client'].PHP_EOL;
}
/* c++ occi code */
string q("select client from test");
ora_stmt = ora_conn->createStatement (q);

ora_stmt->setPrefetchRowCount(1000);  // THIS IS AN ANSWER

ResultSet *rset = ora_stmt->executeQuery();
while (rset->next ())
{
    i++;
    if (i%1000 == 0) cout << i << endl;
}
```

Is the any way to improve occi?

**My answer:**

```
ora_stmt->setPrefetchRowCount(1000);
```

Comment: Did you time a debug build or a release build (with optimizations enabled)? I'm guessing the former...

Comment: I don't know either library, but I suspect that one buffers the results and the other one doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

A quick scan through the docs reveals what @unapersson above mentions could be correct, once you have constructed the `Statement`, before executing the query, it may be worth playing around with the following settings:

> `setPrefetchMemorySize()`
>
> Set the amount of memory that will be
>   used internally by OCCI to store data
>   fetched during each round trip to the
>   server.
>
> `setPrefetchRowCount()`
>
> Set the number of rows that will be
>   fetched internally by OCCI during each
>   round trip to the server.

I am under the impression that as it stands, each call to `next()` could be triggering a round-trip to the server.

Comment: Yes, This is a response.
Thank you very much!

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know PHP, so I cannot really comment on that side. On the C++ side of things, you are *flushing* the output stream after each write, which could be a good amount of *unneeded* flushing. Remove the `endl` and use `'\n'` and test again:

```
if ( i % 1000 == 0 ) cout << i << '\n';
```

Comment: hmm, I seriously doubt the flushing is the problem, he's looking at 50K rows, which means only 50 `couts` happen, which in the grand context of things is... well.. nothing really...